# nz-virtual-scroll not display the tfoot when used?

Tags: node.js, angular, ng-zorro-antd

I am trying to display the tfoot when using Virtual Scroll in nz-table, but when the interface is displayed, the tfoot completely disappears. I have used [nzFooter], but the tfoot is not in the same table, and the scrollbar at this point is malfunctioning.Please help, where did I go wrong?

Here is the code example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6kwws?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,node_modules%2Fng-zorro-antd%2Ftable%2Fsrc%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.d.ts,node_modules%2F%40angular%2Fcdk%2Fscrolling%2Findex.d.ts,node_modules%2Fng-zorro-antd%2Ftable%2Fsrc%2Ftable%2Ftable-virtual-scroll.directive.d.ts